# Unarchive Google firebase dynamic link

Tags: firebase

### Is there any way to "unarchive" a dynamic link in Google firebase?

I archived a firebase dynamic link thinking I wouldn't be using it, to tidy up the console. Now I've changed my mind.
The link still works, but I can't find a way to unarchive it/bring it back onto the dynamic links page in console, so that the deep link can be edited in future. Trying to create a new link using the same short-link gives an error ('already in use'). Without being able to edit the deep link, the short link is now essentially unusable.

Any advice other than forget it and move on?

Comment: I have discovered a way to bring back the edit page manually, but worried this may change in future; also that it still won't bring the link back to the console. To access the edit page of an archived link, you can modify the edit page url of an existing/not archived link. e.g. if an existing link can be edited at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my-project/durablelinks/edit?linkUrl=https:%2F%2Fmy-project.page.link%2Ftest-1502, just change the linkUrl to that of the archived link and it will allow you to edit it.